# Proving that a matrix is skew Hermitian

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n} $ is skew hermitian: $A^* = -A$. Suppose $B$ is unitarily similar to $A$: That is there is some unitary matrix $Q$ such that $A = Q^{-1} B Q $. I want to show that $B$ must be skew hermitian

#### Attempt;

We know $Q^* = Q $ as $Q$ is unitary. Also, we can write $B = QAQ^{-1}$ and so

$$ B^* = (QAQ^{-1})^* = Q^{-1} (-A) Q = - Q^{-1} A Q  $$

Can we assume that $Q^{-1} = Q $ as well? so that we can get $-B$ on the right hand side?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_matrix

Comment: Got it! Does this still holds for real matrices? That is, if $A$ satisfies only $A^T = -A$ ?

Comment: If $A$ is such a real matrix, then $A^*=\overline{A}^T=A^T=-A$. So yes. (Assuming this is the only thing you change in your statement.)

Comment: There is something wrong here: a unitary matrix $Q$ does not necessarily satisfy $Q^*=Q$, however it satisfies $Q^*=Q^{-1}$. Take a permutation matrix for an easy counterexample.